# Django not logging and redirecting user

Tags: python, django

I am creating a simple register and login system for my Django web application. I am able to successfully create a user and save it to the Django database, but I am struggling with logging a user in. I want to log a user in and redirect them to the dashboard.html page, but it won't work. All of my code is down below.

---

**Views.py**

```
def index(request,*args, **kwargs):
  return render(request, "index.html", {} )

def dashboard(request,*args, **kwargs):
  return render(request, "dashboard.html", {} )

def register(request, ):
  form = CreateUserForm()
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
      messages.success(request, f'Your account has been successfully created, {username} ')
      return redirect('loginpage')
  context = {'form': form}
  return render(request, "register.html",  context )



def loginpage(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(request, username =username, password = password)

    if user is not None:
      login(request, user)
      return redirect('dashboard')
  context = {}
  return render(request,"login.html")
```

**Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('home/',views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('register/',views.register, name = 'register'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', views.loginpage, name = 'loginpage' ),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name = 'dashboard' ),
]
```

**Forms.py:**

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
  username = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=30, ) 
  email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
  first_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
  last_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
  

  
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2',]
  #function to display errors
  def clean(self):
          cleaned_data=super().clean()
          password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
          password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

          if User.objects.filter(username=cleaned_data["username"]).exists():
            raise ValidationError("This username is taken, please try another one")

          elif password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("2 password fields do not match")

          elif len(password1) < 8 or len(password2) < 8:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must be at least 8 characters long")
```

**login.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'loginstyles.css' %}">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>GoodDeed - Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for message in messages %}
    <p  id="messages">{{message}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  <!-- Form-->
<div class="form">
  <div class="form-toggle"></div>
  <div class="form-panel one">
      <div class="form-header">
          <h1>Account Login</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="form-content">
          <form>
            {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="form-group"><label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" id="username" name="username" required="required" /></div>
              <div class="form-group"><label for="password">Password</label><input type="password" id="password" name="password" required="required" /></div>
              <div class="form-group"><label class="form-remember"><input type="checkbox" />Remember Me</label><a class="form-recovery" href="#">Forgot Password?</a></div>
              <div class="form-group"><button type="submit">Log In</button></div>
              <div id="register"><a href="/register">Don't have an account? Sign Up Here!</a></div>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
  
          
      </div>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

where is your login form?? I can't see any form in your login view. First make a login form

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=255, label="Username or Email")
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=255, label="Password")
```

And write your view that way

```
def loginpage(request):
  form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
  if form.is_valid():
    username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
    user = authenticate(request, username =username, password = password)
    if user is not None:
      login(request, user)
      return redirect('dashboard')
  context = {'form': form}
  return render(request,"login.html", context)
```

and the template will be

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<input type='submit' value='login'>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, my login form is an html file.  Is it necessary to make another one? I will update my  question with the login form html

Comment: add method to your form like that cause you're making a post request,                  <form method="POST">...</form>

Comment: What do you mean by adding a method to my form? Can you please update your answer with the entire views.py file? Thank you

Comment: added template on my code snippet. But if you want to take your template than just add a method on your template and I think with that your loginview will be works.

Comment: Wait so where would I make the login form?

Comment: create a python file and name as 'forms.py', then import it on your views